# ASP.NET Core Web API cannot find my DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core web app where I have added the `DbContext`:

```
string connectionString = builder.Configuration
    .GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") 
    ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<HomeNotificationsDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddHomeNotificationApplicationServices(typeof(IUserService));
```

The `AddHomeNotificationApplicationServices` method is an extension method that registers all of my services via reflection as scoped. That launches just fine. But whenever I try to launch it alongside a Web API where I register the same services with the same method, I get the following error:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'HomeNotifications.Data.HomeNotificationsDbContext' while attempting to activate 'HomeNotifications.Services.Data.HomeAuthenticationService'.

The `HomeAuthenticationService` uses dependency injection to create a read-only instance of the `DbContext`:

```
public class HomeAuthenticationService : IHomeAuthenticationService
{
    private readonly HomeNotificationsDbContext dbContext;

    public HomeAuthenticationService(HomeNotificationsDbContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    // ...
}
```

I tried adding the `DbContext` as a scoped service in the API, as I don't have access to the configuration settings of the web app there, but that didn't work out. I could add the connection string to the API configuration file, but I'm not sure if that is the correct approach as I'm a rather new developer. Any tips would be appreciated.

EDIT: To add further clarification, my DbContext, Web and Web API are all in different class libraries. The DbContext is initialized with DI in my services, and my services are again initialized with DI in my Web API and Razor pages. Picture for reference: [image: home_notifications_app_structure]

As explained in the reply to the comment below, I solved my problem by registering the services only in the Web Program.cs and doing no registration in the Web API Program.cs.

Comment: Does your DbContext and main web app within the same project or they are in different class library? Would kindly share your project structure as well?

Answer (score 0):

> I tried adding the DbContext as a scoped service in the API, as I
> don't have access to the configuration settings of the web app there,
> but that didn't work out. I could add the connection string to the API
> configuration file,

Well, based on your scenario and description I have tired to investigate your issue and I couldn't reproduce the error you are getting.

Based on my test, I think you should check couple of things.

First of all, if DbContext is registered once in the Program.cs files of both applications outside of the shared service registration method AddHomeNotificationApplicationServices. This entails moving the HomeNotificationsDbContext registration into both Program.cs files' ConfigureServices method and excluding it from the extension method's registration logic.

By doing so, you prevent duplicate DbContext registrations and enable seamless sharing of the DbContext between the applications, effectively resolving the dependency injection conflict.

In addition, if you dbContext proejct reside in different project then make sure you have added the reference within your main project. Becuase, the error indicating, DI has not been injected accordingly.

Another important thing is your project structure. I am not sure how it is. But I have tried with following project structure and Its working without any error and I have able to pull value from database.

[image]

Let me share,how I have tired:

DbContext Clas:

```
using DbContextTestApp.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace DbContextTestApp.Data
{
    public class HomeNotificationsDbContext: DbContext
    {
        public HomeNotificationsDbContext(DbContextOptions<HomeNotificationsDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller Class:

```
using DbContextTestApp.Data;
using DbContextTestApp.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace DbContextTestApp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private readonly HomeNotificationsDbContext _context;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, HomeNotificationsDbContext context)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
           var employees = _context.Employees;
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** Web API project has not difference while adding DbContext class.

Program.cs:

```
using DbContextTestApp.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<HomeNotificationsDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:** Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/) in order to know the [configuration details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/).